# Очистка файла перед записью

Tags: файлы, golang

Задался вопросом в процессе разработки, каким же образом перед записью в файл его можно очистить?

К примеру в текстовом файле у меня содержится на первой строке словосочетание "Привет, мир!".
В зависимости от ситуации, которая произойдет в потоке выполнения программы я бы хотел перезаписать значение, например на "Прощай, мир!".
Но если просто повторно произвести операцию file.WriteString("Прощай, мир!"), то произойдет конкатенация.

В таком случае нужно, чтобы перед записью файл очистился, курсор переставился на нулевую позицию, что ли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите очистить при открытии, то просто передайте
в [`OpenFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/os#OpenFile)
флаг
[`O_TRUNC`](https://golang.org/pkg/os#O_TRUNC). При работе
с уже открытым же файлом, вам нужно вызвать метод
[`Seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.Seek)
для «перемотки» в начало и метод
[`Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/os#File.Truncate)
для уменьшения размера файла:

```golang
_, _ = f.WriteString("Hello, world!\n")
check(err)

_, err = f.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
check(err)

err = f.Truncate(0)
check(err)

_, err = f.WriteString("Goodbye, world!\n")
check(err)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!